# Excel VBA macros for data set

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I need to create a csv file from data set matrix, in which I have materials as a rows, people as a columns and quantity of products on intersection. Here is an example of this data set (Order id #1000):

```
Materials  Person1  Person2  
563718       20       40
837563       15       35
```

As a first action I have to transform this data set to a linear structure in this way on additional sheet:

```
Orderid   Material   Person    Qty
1000      563718     Person1   20
1000      837563     Person1   15
1000      563718     Person2   40
1000      837563     Person2   35
```

And from this linear structure I have to generate a csv file with Orders for another system based on unique Persons from the list above. Each Order should have one header line and details based on the number of materials he/she ordered. General structure is the following:

```
H,1000-1,OUT,20160830,Person1
l,1000-1,1,563718,20,EA
l,1000-1,2,837563,15,EA
H,1000-2,OUT,20160830,Person2
l,1000-2,1,563718,40,EA
l,1000-2,2,837563,15,EA
```

where "H" - means Header row, "1000-1" - first Sub-Order of a Global order 1000, "20160830" requested delivery date, "l" - line row, "1" - line number, "EA" - unit of measure.

Comment: We generally try to help people learn to fish. If you just want a fish to be handed to you, look towards the job link and find someone that you would be willing to pay. They will appreciate it. OR, post your macro code where you have tried to accomplish this along with a description of errors or where you are getting hung up and we will be happy to help you get past those errors and issues.

Comment: You could start by recording a macro while you `unpivot` your basic column (using `Power Pivot` or `Data` ► `Get and Transform`); add in your index column and the other modifications you need, and save as `csv`.  Then edit your macro to clean it up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro that will get you most of the way.  It takes the data in your first table and organizes it so that your date in like columns (person1 and person2) is separated into separate rows:

This script assumes that your fixed column(s) are on the left and the columns to be combined (and split out into multiple rows) follow on the right. I hope this helps!

```
Option Explicit

Sub MatrixConverter2_3()

' Macro created 11/16/2005 by Peter T Oboyski (updated 8/24/2006)
'
' *** Substantial changes made by Chris Brackett (updated 8/3/2016) ***
'
' You are welcome to redistribute this macro, but if you make substantial
' changes to it, please indicate so in this section along with your name.
' This Macro converts matrix-type spreadsheets (eg. plot x species data) into column data
' The new (converted) spreadsheet name is "DB of 'name of active spreadsheet'"
' The conversion allows for multiple header rows and columns.

'--------------------------------------------------
' This section declares variables for use in the script

Dim book, head, cels, mtrx, dbase, v, UserReady, columnsToCombine, RowName, DefaultRowName, DefaultColName1, DefaultColName2, ColName As String
Dim defaultHeaderRows, defaultHeaderColumns, c, r, selectionCols, ro, col, newro, newcol, rotot, coltot, all, rowz, colz, tot As Long
Dim headers(100) As Variant
Dim dun As Boolean


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section sets the script defaults

defaultHeaderRows = 1
defaultHeaderColumns = 2

DefaultRowName = "Activity"

'--------------------------------------------------
' This section asks about data types, row headers, and column headers

UserReady = MsgBox("Have you selected the entire data set (not the column headers) to be converted?", vbYesNoCancel)
If UserReady = vbNo Or UserReady = vbCancel Then GoTo EndMatrixMacro

all = MsgBox("Exclude zeros and empty cells?", vbYesNoCancel)
If all = vbCancel Then GoTo EndMatrixMacro


' UN-COMMENT THIS SECTION TO ALLOW FOR MULTIPLE HEADER ROWS
rowz = 1
' rowz = InputBox("How many HEADER ROWS?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "(Usually 1)", "Header Rows & Columns", defaultHeaderRows)
' If rowz = vbNullString Then GoTo EndMatrixMacro

colz = InputBox("How many HEADER COLUMNS?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "(These are the columns on the left side of your data set to preserve as is.)", "Header Rows & Columns", defaultHeaderColumns)
If colz = vbNullString Then GoTo EndMatrixMacro


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section allows the user to provide field (column) names for the new spreadsheet

selectionCols = Selection.Columns.Count ' get the number of columns in the selection
For r = 1 To selectionCols
    headers(r) = Selection.Cells(1, r).Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Value ' save the column headers to use as defaults for user provided names
Next r

colz = colz * 1
columnsToCombine = "'" & Selection.Cells(1, colz + 1).Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Value & "' to '" & Selection.Cells(1, selectionCols).Offset(rowOffset:=-1, columnOffset:=0).Value & "'"

Dim Arr(20) As Variant
newcol = 1
For r = 1 To rowz
    If r = 1 Then RowName = DefaultRowName
    Arr(newcol) = InputBox("Field name for the fields/columns to be combined" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & columnsToCombine, , RowName)
    If Arr(newcol) = vbNullString Then GoTo EndMatrixMacro
    newcol = newcol + 1
Next
For c = 1 To colz
    ColName = headers(c)
    Arr(newcol) = InputBox("Field name for column " & c, , ColName)
    If Arr(newcol) = vbNullString Then GoTo EndMatrixMacro
    newcol = newcol + 1
Next
Arr(newcol) = "Data"
v = newcol

'--------------------------------------------------
' This section creates the new spreadsheet, names it, and color codes the new worksheet tab

mtrx = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
dbase = "DB of " & mtrx

'--------------------------------------------------
' If the proposed worksheet name is longer than 28 characters, truncate it to 29 characters.
    If Len(dbase) > 28 Then dbase = Left(dbase, 28)


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section checks if the proposed worksheet name
'  already exists and appends adds a sequential number
'  to the name
    Dim sheetExists As Variant
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim iName As Integer

    Dim dbaseOld As String
    dbaseOld = dbase    ' save the original proposed name of the new worksheet

    iName = 0

    sheetExists = False
CheckWorksheetNames:

    For Each Sheet In Worksheets    ' loop through every worksheet in the workbook
        If dbase = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            iName = iName + 1
            dbase = Left(dbase, Len(dbase) - 1) & " " & iName
            GoTo CheckWorksheetNames
            ' Exit For
        End If
    Next Sheet


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section notify the user if the proposed
' worksheet name is already being used and the new
' worksheet was given an alternate name

    If sheetExists = True Then
        MsgBox "The worksheet '" & dbaseOld & "' already exists.  Renaming to '" & dbase & "'."
    End If


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section creates and names a new worksheet
    On Error Resume Next    'Ignore errors
        If Sheets("" & Range(dbase) & "") Is Nothing Then   ' If the worksheet name doesn't exist
            ActiveSheet.Name = dbase    ' Rename newly created worksheet
        Else
            MsgBox "Cannot name the worksheet '" & dbase & "'.  A worksheet with that name already exists."
            GoTo EndMatrixMacro
        End If
    On Error GoTo 0         ' Resume normal error handling

    Sheets(dbase).Tab.ColorIndex = 41 ' color the worksheet tab


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section turns off screen and calculation updates so that the script
' can run faster.  Updates are turned back on at the end of the script.
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'--------------------------------------------------
'This section determines how many rows and columns the matrix has

dun = False
rotot = rowz + 1
Do
    If (Sheets(mtrx).Cells(rotot, 1) > 0) Then
        rotot = rotot + 1
    Else
        dun = True
    End If
Loop Until dun
rotot = rotot - 1

dun = False
coltot = colz + 1
Do
    If (Sheets(mtrx).Cells(1, coltot) > 0) Then
        coltot = coltot + 1
    Else
        dun = True
    End If
Loop Until dun
coltot = coltot - 1


'--------------------------------------------------
'This section writes the new field names to the new spreadsheet

For newcol = 1 To v
    Sheets(dbase).Cells(1, newcol) = Arr(newcol)
Next


'--------------------------------------------------
'This section actually does the conversion

tot = 0
newro = 2
For col = (colz + 1) To coltot
    For ro = (rowz + 1) To rotot 'the next line determines if data are nonzero
        If ((Sheets(mtrx).Cells(ro, col) <> 0) Or (all <> 6)) Then   'DCB modified ">0" to be "<>0" to exclude blank and zero cells
            tot = tot + 1
            newcol = 1
            For r = 1 To rowz            'the next line copies the row headers
                Sheets(dbase).Cells(newro, newcol) = Sheets(mtrx).Cells(r, col)
                newcol = newcol + 1
            Next
            For c = 1 To colz         'the next line copies the column headers
                Sheets(dbase).Cells(newro, newcol) = Sheets(mtrx).Cells(ro, c)
                newcol = newcol + 1
            Next                                'the next line copies the data
            Sheets(dbase).Cells(newro, newcol) = Sheets(mtrx).Cells(ro, col)
            newro = newro + 1
        End If
    Next
Next


'--------------------------------------------------
'This section displays a message box with information about the conversion

book = "Original matrix = " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ": " & mtrx & Chr(10)
head = "Matrix with " & rowz & " row headers and " & colz & " column headers" & Chr(10)
cels = tot & " cells of " & ((rotot - rowz) * (coltot - colz)) & " with data"


'--------------------------------------------------
' This section turns screen and calculation updates back ON.
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True


MsgBox (book & head & cels)


'--------------------------------------------------
' This is an end point for the macro

EndMatrixMacro:

End Sub
```

Comment: Some feedback on the down vote would be useful!

Comment: Not my downvote, but at a glance that code declares a truckload of implicit `Variant` locals, scrolls forever and smells like it needs some serious refactoring, be it only to remove these `GoTo` jumps from 1980 and split responsibilities a bit.

Comment: In my defense, I'm an accountant, and the code works : )  Appreciate the feedback though.  I start with `Option Explicit` so aren't all the variables explicit?  What's the reason to avoid using `GoTo` jumps?  This runs quick even with fairly large data sets.  Can you point me to any resources about better alternatives?  Thanks!

Comment: `Option Explicit` ensures all variables are *declared*, but not specifying an explicit type (e.g. `Dim foo As String`) makes a variable a `Variant` that can be assigned and reassigned to just about anything; `GoTo` is frowned upon because it makes code harder to follow... and can spawn [deadly raptors](https://xkcd.com/292/) - I can't fit much more in a comment, but feel free to put your code up for peer review on [codereview.se]; VBA reviewers will enjoy such a meaty piece! See [how to get the best value out of CR](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436/23788) to make a *great* post!

Comment: Raptor...hehe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @ChrisB for your answer. Actually I decided to do it my own way and here are the main steps I did:

1. I created an Excel file with several buttons to which I assigned below Subroutines. Also I have added some parameters, which user can modify (OrderId, Delivery Date and WH id).
2. I created a Subroutine ReadData(), which clears the Sheet "DATA" in original file and after reads column by column in the data file and generates a linear data set with all required fields on "DATA" Sheet.
3. After that I simply writes "DATA" sheet to external csv file.

the final code looks like this:

```
Global Const DAODBEngine = "DAO.DBEngine.36"
Global intColBeg As Integer                 'Column Index with Data set to analyze
Global intRowBeg As Integer                 'Row Index with Data set to analyze


Sub FileOpen()
    Dim filePath As String
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Cells(4, 3) = filePath
End Sub

Sub ClearData()
    ' Check if DATA Sheet exists
    If Evaluate("ISREF('" & "DATA" & "'!A1)") Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "DATA"

End Sub


' This function reads data and adds it to DATA Sheet

Sub ReadData()
    Dim i As Integer, l As Integer
    Dim intColumn As Integer, intRow As Integer
    Dim intAddRow As Integer
    Dim wbCopyFrom As Workbook
    Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
    Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
    Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim dataLoc As String, wbLoc As String
    Dim mandant As String
    Dim orderId As String
    Dim orderNum As Integer
    Dim shipDate As Date

    dataLoc = Trim(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BASE").Cells(4, 3).Text)

    Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(dataLoc)
    Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets(1)

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Call ClearData              ' Clears all the data on DATA Sheet

    Set wbCopyTo = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsCopyTo = wbCopyTo.Sheets("DATA")

    wbCopyTo.Activate

    mandant = wbCopyTo.Sheets("BASE").Cells(11, 3).Text
    orderId = wbCopyTo.Sheets("BASE").Cells(7, 3).Text
    shipDate = wbCopyTo.Sheets("BASE").Cells(9, 3).Text


    ' Initial upper left row/column where matrix data begins

    intColBeg = 4
    intRowBeg = 4

    intColumn = intColBeg
    intRow = intRowBeg
    intAddRow = 1               ' We will add data from this row

    orderNum = 1

    While Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(intRowBeg - 1, intColumn).Text) <> ""

        ' Header of an Order

        wsCopyTo.Cells(intAddRow, 1) = "H;OUT;" & mandant & ";" & orderId & "/" & orderNum & ";" & _
                ";;" & Mid(shipDate, 7, 4) & Mid(shipDate, 4, 2) & Mid(shipDate, 1, 2) & ";" & _
                Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(3, intColumn).Text) & ";" & Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(2, intColumn).Text) & _
                ";;;;;;;999;;"

        Dim r As Integer

        r = 1

        intAddRow = intAddRow + 1

        While Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(intRow, intColBeg - 1).Text) <> ""
            If (Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(intRow, intColumn).Text) <> "") Then
                If Round(CDbl(Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(intRow, intColumn).Value)), 0) > 0 Then

                    ' Rows of an Order

                    wsCopyTo.Cells(intAddRow, 1) = "I;" & orderId & "/" & orderNum & ";" & r & ";" & _
                    Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(intRow, 1).Text) & ";" & Trim(wsCopyFrom.Cells(intRow, intColumn).Value) & _
                    ";PCE;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;"

                    r = r + 1

                    intAddRow = intAddRow + 1
                End If
            End If

            intRow = intRow + 1
        Wend

        intRow = intRowBeg

        intColumn = intColumn + 1

        orderNum = orderNum + 1

    Wend

    wbCopyFrom.Close
    wbCopyTo.Sheets("BASE").Activate

End Sub

Sub Export()
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFileName As String

MyFileName = "Orders_" & Sheets("BASE").Cells(7, 3).Text & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")

If Not Right(MyFileName, 4) = ".csv" Then MyFileName = MyFileName & ".csv"

Sheets("DATA").Copy

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "" '<~~ The start folder path for the file picker.
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    MyPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

NextCode:

If MyPath <> "" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs fileName:=MyPath & MyFileName, AccessMode:=xlExclusive, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges
        .Close False
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I believe that this code isn't optimal as I don't have any experience in VBA and it was a method of trying/changing/trying again in debugging mode and googling in case of issues.

If you can provide any suggestion how to optimise it - that would be great!